# Attribute Error: folium has no attribute map

Tags: python, pandas, folium

The error I am getting is like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-637818dcbe0d> in <module>
----> 1 mp = folium.map(location=[151.1780,33.7961], zoom_start=10)
      2 
      3 choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
      4             geo_data=suburbs,
      5             data=rentwpostcode,

AttributeError: module 'folium' has no attribute 'map'
```

I tried installing folium through both conda and git clone. Both times the error remained. I also tried to removing `folium.py` but still it didn't work.

Comment: What os are you using? What python version?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is not related to the installation of `folium`. Names in Python are case-sensitive so `.map()` is not the same as `.Map()`. Change your code to  `mp = folium.Map(location=[151.1780,33.7961], zoom_start=10)` and it'll work fine.